# Double dot at the end of sentence when figure reference ends with a dot

Tags: cross-referencing, punctuation, documentclass-writing

I try to make a class. I wrote

```
\renewcommand\thetable{\thechapter\arabic{table}.}
```

and under the table or in sentence I have e.g. "Table 2.1." but problem is when reference is at the end of sentence, e.g.:

```
Example sentences with reference \ref{tab.some}.
```

gives

> Example sentences with reference Table 2.1..

Similar problem for figures.

Comment: Remove the `.` at the end of `\renewcommand\thetable{\thechapter\arabic{table}.}`. Is there any thing wrong with that?

Comment: Is the main reason for wanting to have a `.` (dot) after  table and figure number a desire to have the caption's "number" be followed by a dot rather than a colon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statically changing the reference mechanisms to end by dots is, in my opinion, bad practice. It forces your structures. It is also unclear in the code how it should be interpreted, for instance:

```
Bla bla  ... as is seen in \ref{tab.some} Hence we can conclude
```

in my view this looks like you forgot a `.`, however, that is not the case.
Why would you have a dot after the reference?
Also your reference is not an abbreviation, hence, adding a dot is unnecessary.

My recommendation is to use this:

```
\renewcommand\thetable{\thechapter\arabic{table}}
```

Else you need to look ahead and parse the `.`. This can be done with something like:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thetable{\thechapter\arabic{table}\@ifnextchar.\relax.}
\makeatother
```

however, the above may have deficiencies.

Comment: Thank you for your answers (very quick!).

I got a template in MS Word 2007, and I done the same in Tex / LaTeX.
Now I read it one more time and the problem is partialy solved - I made one mistake - reference in text should be without end-dot e.g. 

> Bla bla bla Table 2.1, bla bla Figure 2.1.

But dots should appear in caption, e.g.

> Table 2.1. Data from product user.

Which is my new problem ;)

Answer (score 8):

You want `dot` in caption and don't in references. This can be done with `caption` package. Redefine the `labelsep` like

```
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period}
```

separately or you can simply put

```
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}
```

and it is applicable to both figures and tables.

A small example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Some chapter}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Some caption}\label{tab:mytable}
Some table comes here
\end{table}

I refer to Table~\ref{tab:mytable} and my Figure~\ref{fig:myfig} here in text.
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Some figure}\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this help - It turned out that earlier I put the caption package, but I write "labelsep = space". I change to period and now it looks fine.